# In Rails, what is the best way to return a RecordNotFound Error from a Model.find call in JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, api

What should be the right response for a RecordNotFound Error when doing something like this:

```
def destroy
    @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    head :no_content
  end
```

Comment: Why are you looking up `@post` to not use it? Where is `@request` defined?

Answer (score 0):

You may write as follows:

```
def destroy
  @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  flash[:notice] = "Record Not Found"
  @post .destroy

  head :no_content
end
```